# Using lib pragma after explicitly setting @INC has no effect

Tags: perl

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;
BEGIN {
    @INC = qw(dir1 dir2); # <-- lib pragma works fine if I omit this line
    # @INC = ();  <-- this is what I wanted to do
    use lib 'dir3';
}
say for @INC;
```

**Output**:

```
dir1
dir2
```

**Expected output**:

```
dir3
dir1
dir2
```

Comment: Strange, If I use `use lib 'dir3';` in another `BEGIN` block it gives me expected output.

Comment: @AbhiNickz Yes, it seems  like the `use lib` adds another `BEGIN{}` block, that somehow gets evaluated before the `BEGIN` block it is in...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A `use` statement is contained within an implicit `BEGIN` block, and 
all Perl `BEGIN` blocks in a program are are executed as soon as they finish compilation

That means you have nested `BEGIN` blocks here, and because the inner one—the `use lib 'dir3'` statement—finishes compilation at the end of the statement, it is the first to be executed. It is followed by the closing brace of the explicit `BEGIN` block, which completes *that* block's compilation and it is only then that those statements are executed

Here is a sample program that uses only `say` statements, and replaces the `use` statement in the original with an explicit `BEGIN` block

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

BEGIN {

    say "outer BEGIN";

    BEGIN {
        say "inner BEGIN";
    }
}
```

#### output

```
inner BEGIN
outer BEGIN
```

Your code works as if you had written it like this

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

use lib 'dir3';

BEGIN {
    @INC = qw(dir1 dir2);
}

say for @INC;
```

So the `use lib` is executed first, adding `dir3` to `@INC`, and then the explicit `BEGIN` block is executed and overwrites `@INC` altogether

If you want to empty `@INC` first and then add to it with `use lib` statements then you should write

```
BEGIN {
    our @INC = ( );
}

use lib 'dir3';
```

Without the nesting, `BEGIN` blocks are executed in the order the appear in the program

Answer (score -1):

From [perldoc - lib](http://perldoc.perl.org/lib.html)

> This is a small simple module which simplifies the manipulation of @INC at *compile time*.

When you insert `say for @INC;` after the opening brace and before the assignment, e.g.

```
BEGIN {
    say for @INC;
    @INC = qw(dir1 dir2); # <-- lib pragma works fine if I omit this line
    # @INC = ();  <-- this is what I wanted to do
    use lib 'dir3';
}
```

You will see `dir3` listed.

---

And [perldoc - use](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html) states

> Because use takes effect at compile time, it doesn't respect the ordinary flow control of the code being compiled.

`dir3` is inserted into `@INC` before anything else is executed, and then `@INC` is assigned the new value (`dir1, dir2`). You see this new assigned value, when you look at `@INC` finally.

Comment: Yes this gives a clue to what is going on.. but why is `@INC` no longer as I expected at run time?